# Find the closest number based on the weight of combination for two pairs

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

This is a continuation of my previous question [What is the efficient way to generate combination of items in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12928718/what-is-the-efficient-way-to-generate-combination-of-items-in-sql-server) Let me explain the real scenario as what I am looking for and why....

Suppose I have a table as under

```
Declare @t table(Number Int)
Insert Into @t Values(10),(20),(30),(40),(18)

Number
10
20
30
40
18
```

and I need to look for a number say 35 (or closest).

```
Declare @NumberToLookfor = 35
```

Now the search will happen based on the weight of combination for two pairs. Let me explain.

```
10+20 = 30

10+30 = 40

10+40 = 50

10+18 = 28

20 + 30 = 50

20 + 40 = 60

20 + 18 = 38

30 + 40 = 70

30 + 18 = 48

40 + 18 = 58
```

so we can figure out that the weight of any two numbers are teh candidates here e.g. (10,20), (10,30)...(40,18)

Once we get that, the first 3 closest pairs will be (20,18), (10,20) , (10,30) in this case. Because teh dirtance between 35 and 38 (20+18) is 3 whichle it is 5 for the other pairs  (10,20) , (10,30).

I think that the explanation is clear to understand what I am looking for.(If not please let me know)

What is the most efficient way of doing so?

My attempt

```
Declare @t table(Number Int)
Insert Into @t Values(10),(20),(30),(40),(18)

;WITH Cte1 (Number,Ids,TotalWeight) AS 
( 
    SELECT  Number           
            , ',' + CAST(Number AS VARCHAR(MAX)) 
            ,CAST(Number AS INT) 
    FROM @t 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT  p.Number 
            ,c.Ids + ',' +  CAST(p.Number AS VARCHAR(MAX)) 
            ,CAST(c.TotalWeight + p.Number AS INT)            
    FROM @t AS p JOIN Cte1 c ON p.Number < c.Number
),Cte2 AS( 
    SELECT          
        *
        ,DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY ABS(TotalWeight - 35)) [rank] 
    FROM Cte1 
    WHERE (LEN(Ids) - LEN(REPLACE(Ids, ',', '')))/LEN(',') = 2 
)

select *
from Cte2 where [rank] <= 2
```

It works.

[image]

But if the values grows very big say more than 50 or so, then it becomes very very in efficient. Because in the first CTE , I am finding out the full permutation and in the second Cte choosing those values where only two elements participated.

so when the value grows big, the first Cte behaves very very slowly.

Is there any other way of doing so even for big tables.

DDL provided

```
Declare @t table(Number Int)
Insert Into @t Values  
(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12),(13),(14),(15),(16),(17),(18),(19),(20), 
(21),(22),(23),(24),(25),(26),(27),(28),(29),(30),(31),(32),(33),(34),(35),(36),(37),(38),(39),(40), 
(41),(42),(43),(44),(45),(46),(47),(48),(49),(50),(51),(52),(53),(54),(55),(56),(57),(58),(59),(60), 
(61),(62),(63),(64),(65),(66),(67),(68),(69),(70),(71),(72),(73),(74),(75),(76),(77),(78),(79),(80), 
(81),(82),(83),(84),(85),(86),(87),(88),(89),(90),(91),(92),(93),(94),(95),(96),(97),(98),(99),(100)
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: NP-complete problems are quite hard. You need to do some research and implement a proper polynomial solution rather than your brute force approach. BTW, I don't believe someone will implement it in SQL just for you. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To generically solve for pairs, triplets etc using the brute force method for very small sets, this may work. Update the number in the two indicated locations.

```
Declare @t table(Number Int)
Insert Into @t Values(10),(20),(30),(40),(18)

;WITH Cte1 (Counter,Number,Ids,TotalWeight) AS 
( 
    SELECT  1,Number           
            , ',' + CAST(Number AS VARCHAR(MAX)) 
            ,CAST(Number AS INT) 
    FROM @t 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT  c.Counter+1,p.Number 
            ,c.Ids + ',' +  CAST(p.Number AS VARCHAR(MAX)) 
            ,CAST(c.TotalWeight + p.Number AS INT)            
    FROM @t AS p JOIN Cte1 c ON p.Number < c.Number
    WHERE c.Counter < 2   --<<** we need only up to 2 numbers
),Cte2 AS( 
    SELECT          
        *
        ,DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY ABS(TotalWeight - 35)) [rank] 
    FROM Cte1 
    WHERE Counter = 2   --<<** use only the pairs
)

select *
from Cte2 where [rank] <= 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Slightly different result set, but should be vastly more efficient, if all you care about is dealing with pairs:

```
Declare @t table(Number Int)
Insert Into @t Values(10),(20),(30),(40),(18)

;WITH Pairs AS 
( 
    SELECT  t1.Number as p1,t2.Number as p2,t1.Number + t2.Number as TotalWeight
    FROM
        @t t1
            inner join
        @t t2
            on
                t1.Number < t2.Number
),Cte2 AS( 
    SELECT          
        *
        ,DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY ABS(TotalWeight - 35)) [rank] 
    FROM Pairs 
)

select *
from Cte2 where [rank] <= 2
```

Result:

```
p1          p2          TotalWeight rank
----------- ----------- ----------- --------------------
18          20          38          1
10          30          40          2
10          20          30          2
```

Comment: If you want to deal with triples instead, then yes, another inner join would be required. If you want to vary the number involved, Richard's solution may work better for you, but as he indicated in his comment, solving this problem *generally* is an NP-complete problem.